# how to remove duplicate blkid entry

Tags: lvm

I created an lvm and proceeded with formatting the partition /dev/vg1/lvm1 with ext3. However, accidentally i format again the partition but this time i used the device /dev/mapper/vg1-lvm1.

Both files are sym-links to the same device (/dev/dm-7). When i execute the command 'blkid' i see two block devices with the same UUID.

```
/dev/mapper/vg1-lvm1: UUID="3cfe6a6e-2770-4a9d-90f7-a33eef80e6b7" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/vg1/lvm1:        UUID="3cfe6a6e-2770-4a9d-90f7-a33eef80e6b7" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

Could this be an issue?
How can i remove one of those entries?

Answer (score 0):

The device mapper always creates entries in /dev/mapper .
This is perfectly normal behaviour and you should not delete these entries.